# Insert into on duplicate key query for custom update on each row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, case, sql-insert

I can insert/update data based on the following query on a MySQL server.

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, books) 
VALUES 
(1, “book1, book2”), 
(2, “book3, book4”) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE books=“book1, book2”;
```

However, is there a way to set multiple books column values for each row after the UPDATE statement? Something like below but that works :)

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, books) 
VALUES 
(1, “book1, book2”), 
(2, “book3, book4”) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE books 
VALUES (“book1, book2”), (“book3, book4”);
```

If this is not the right approach for this purpose, how should I structure such queries?

Many thanks for any guidance in advance,

Doug

Comment: It’s not clear to me what you mean by “set multiple books column values for each row”. Each row can only have a single book column holding a single value, so when you hit a duplicate id what value do you want to set books to for the row that has that id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the duplicate key is the column `user_id`.

You can use a `CASE` expression:

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, books) VALUES 
(1, 'book1, book2'), 
(2, 'book3, book4') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
books = CASE user_id
  WHEN 1 THEN 'book10, book20'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'book30, book40'
END;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f339971d01d6d42da14953339879ff49).